# Javascript- Why is it a "good thing" that Number.isNaN returns false for a non-numeric string?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Yes, I have read the previous extensive comments on this issue.

YDKJS, Types & Grammar, Chapter 2 says that using `isNaN()` is a bug, because of some internal consistency problems.

I use `isNaN()` in order to see whether using a variable in an arithmetic expression will give me an error.

The currently "approved" ES6 `Number.isNaN()` will tell me that it's OK to use a string which does not coerce to a number in a numeric expression. It seems to me that the subverts the whole purpose of using `isNaN()`.

Why is this a good thing? I don't care about the formal consistency of the language - I just don't want my arithmetic expression to blow up.

Is there a practical situation where `Number.isNaN()` will prevent an error that `window.isNaN()` will not?

Example:

```
var a = 2 / "foo"; // is not a number,
var b = "foo";     // is not a number
var c = 2;         // is a number

alert("a="+a+", window.isNaN(a)="+window.isNaN(a)+", Number.isNaN(a)="+Number.isNaN(a)+", isNaN(a)="+isNaN(a)); //true, true,true
alert("b="+b+", window.isNaN(b)="+window.isNaN(b)+", Number.isNaN(b)="+Number.isNaN(b)+", isNaN(b)="+isNaN(b)); //true, false, true
alert("c="+c+", window.isNaN(c)="+window.isNaN(c)+", Number.isNaN(c)="+Number.isNaN(c)+", isNaN(c)="+isNaN(c)); //false, false, false
```

Comment: `2 / "foo"`, this can't be avoided because it always return `NaN`. Forget it.

Comment: So that leaves the problem that Number.isNaN returns false when given a string which doesn't coerce to a number. And YDKJS says that this is a better result than windows.isNaN which (correctly, in my view) says that such a string is NaN.

Comment: Yes... and I said that in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's perfectly good, but better than the global `isNaN`, the reason is because it only returns `true` when certain value is `NaN`. Unfortunately, `Number.isNaN` won't prevent wrong argument errors as it's not obviously a statement or special thing, it doesn't interpret passed expressions like `/` (division) or any other thing. That's it.

Comment: But Number.isNaN won't catch a string like "foo". Isn't it much more likely that I'll accidentally use a string instead of a number than that I'll use an object?  How is that "safe"?? It will let me say a=2/"foo".